# Importing OpenAI from Langchain giving jest error (typescript)

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-jest, openai-api, langchain

I'm trying to import OpenAI from the langchain library as their documentation instructs with:
`import { OpenAI } from "langchain/llms/openai";`

This works correctly when I run my NodeJS server locally and try requests. However, when I run my tests with jest, I get this error:

```
    /(my_directories)/server/node_modules/langchain/llms/openai.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export * from '../dist/llms/openai.js'
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

    > 1 | import { OpenAI } from "langchain/llms/openai";
```

I've been trying to solve it but can't seem it figure it out.

Here's my jest.config.json:

```
{
  "preset": "ts-jest",
  "rootDir": "../../",
  "testEnvironment": "<rootDir>/src/tests/mongoEnvironment.ts",
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
    "<rootDir>/src/tests/setupFile.ts",
    "<rootDir>/src/tests/jestMocks.ts"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "ts-jest": {
      "tsconfig": "<rootDir>/tsconfig.json",
      "isolatedModules": true
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you will need to add this line to your `jest.config` file

```
transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!(langchain|langsmith))']
```

this will tell jest to ignore anything *but* `langchain` or `langsmith` on transpile opertions.